# How to loop an MP3 file in javafx?

Tags: java, loops, javafx, mp3

I am trying to figure out how to loop an MP3 using eclipse, what am I doing wrong?

```
mediaPlayer2.play();{
    mediaPlayer2.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mediaPlayer2.seek(Duration.ZERO);
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer2.play();  
}
```

This should be the code, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The second call to `play()` in your code is not in the `run()` method of the `endOfMedia` handler, so it won't get called when the media finishes.

But this is not the way to repeat a media player indefinitely anyway. Just do

```
mediaPlayer2.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
mediaPlayer2.play();
```

Comment: Your solution foes not work (as mentioned by others over the net). The media stops after a few repeats